# Str replace with Bash code chunk using three variables: search, replace and subject

Tags: r

I have problems understanding the str replace function in Bash.
I am coming from PHP where the function is named [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Can anyone help me with the following example:

```
search="%body%" # The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle
replace="black" # The replacement value that replaces found search values
subject="<body text='%body%'>" # The string or array being searched and replaced on, otherwise known as the haystack

new_string=`echo ${subject//$search/$replace}`
echo "$new_string"
```

When I saved is at as a script "replace.sh" and run it then it prints:

./replace.sh

```
<body text='black'>
```

When I put it into R Studio as a code chunk it doesnt print anything:

````
```{bash echo=FALSE, comment="", results="asis", message=FALSE, tidy=FALSE}
search="%body%" # The value being searched for, otherwise known as the needle
replace="black" # The replacement value that replaces found search values
subject="<body text='%body%'>" # The string or array being searched and replaced on, otherwise known as the haystack

new_string=`echo ${subject//$search/$replace}`
echo "$new_string"
```
````

Comment: Why `echo`? Just `new_string=${...}`. `I have problems understanding` What part don't you understand? Take a peek at the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html . Remember to check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: My example doesnt print anything. new_string is blank. I need to use echo because I am embedding this into R Studio.

Comment: Your comment made it all confusing. `My example doesnt print anything.` - it does [here on repl](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/PricklyCarefulHypothesis#main.sh). `new_string is blank` no, it is not. `I need to use echo because I am embedding this into R Studio` I have no idea what R studio is. In _bash_, you do not need an echo, just `new_string=${subject//$search/$replace}` (unless you _want_ word splitting and filename expansion, for example). You code is like `echo $(echo $(echo ...)))`, it's an example of useless use of echo.

Comment: Ah, I see that my code actully works, but not in R Studio. I will ask this in the correct forum.

Answer (score 1):

This is bash substitution pattern, in variable `subject` replace **all** occurrences of "body" with "black".

All occurrences because of `//`, single slash would cause only the first occurrence being replaced. Maybe this example would make it more clear:

```sh
$ string="aaaaa"
$ echo $string
aaaaa
$ echo ${string/a/b}
baaaa
$ echo ${string//a/b}
bbbbb
```

More information is in this nice article, see chapter number 5:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

Comment: new_string=`echo ${subject/$search/$replace}` does not print anything

Comment: Did you defined those variable before? What does `echo $subject $search $replace` print?

Comment: I see that my code actully works in Bash, but not as embedded code chunk in R Studio. I will ask this in the correct forum.